# Changing the width of PropertyGrid left-side collection editor/view

Tags: c#, .net, collections, propertygrid

Anything with a long string simply introduces an unusable view with a scrollbar..

Is the width on collection editor fixed by the-design and can a splitter be introduced to this awesome presentation?

Comment: edited answer to show reflection-based solution

Comment: Will accept the answer as you really seem to be busy and active with prop-grid and generally winforms stuff :) Thanks.. Off topic, now I am starting to have nightmares on hooking/searching for the collection-view property grid from another property grid with a similar method.. cheers.

Comment: For info, what you are describing is the modal UITypeEditor such as CollectionEditor (just in case that helps the search...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't seen a way to do this with regular `PropertyGrid`, but if you don't mind paying, Visualhint have a much more developed offering [here](http://www.visualhint.com/index.php/propertygrid/) - perhaps trial it.

---

This does the job using reflection; use with caution...

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Form form = new Form();
        // this bar will control the splitter
        ScrollBar sb = new HScrollBar {
            Minimum = 10, Maximum = 200,
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        };
        // the grid we want to control
        PropertyGrid grid = new PropertyGrid {
            SelectedObject = form, Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        // add to the form
        form.Controls.Add(grid);
        form.Controls.Add(sb);
        // event to update the grid
        sb.ValueChanged += delegate {
            MoveSplitterTo(grid, sb.Value);
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
    static void MoveSplitterTo(PropertyGrid grid, int x) {
        // HEALTH WARNING: reflection can be brittle...
        FieldInfo field = typeof(PropertyGrid)
            .GetField("gridView",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        field.FieldType
            .GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Invoke(field.GetValue(grid), new object[] { x });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.. but really am looking for one shipped with 250MB framework to have the ability.